# Como corrigir valor do MPAndroidChart fica por cima quando é 0

Tags: java, android

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tendo esse problema quando uso o MPAndroidChart, alguém sabe me dizer se tem algum método para colocar um espaçamento entre um valor e outro? para não ficar assim por cima? Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Fala Rafael,

Você pretende mostrar no gráfico mesmo quando o valor for 0?

Porque você pode adicionar ao gráfico, somente quando o valor for maior que 0, exemplo:

```
if(value > 0){
   dataSet.add(...)
} else {
   // faz nada
}
```

Abraços.

Comment: Sim, porque as vezes por exemplo são 3 dados, um deles pode vir com 24mil e o outro com 10, ai eu tenho que exibir do mesmo jeito, queria saber se tem como eu colocar um espaçamento entre os textos pra não ficar desse jeito